# Is it possible to run Matlab code when dropping a new Simulink block in a model?

Tags: matlab, simulink, modeling

I would like to run Matlab code when I drop a new Simulink block in my model. Kind of like a callback which exist for existing blocks. Is it at all possible to do that?

Comment: What have you looked at doing/tried to do so far?

Comment: I think I found something. I think I can use the CopyFcn callback to launch code when I insert my subsystems from my own simulink library.

Comment: Yes, this is one of the uses of the block's CopyFcn.